# Sitecore Advanced Database Crawler Field Exclusion

Tags: sitecore, lucene.net, web-crawler, adc

I have a need to create a specific index to perform a search on a particular field from an inherited template. That part of creating the index and returning matching results is fairly straight forward.

The issue I am having is that when doing a search that would not be an intended match for the field, I am getting false results because the Lucene.NET document field '_name' contains the search criteria and is considering that a match.

I am using the Advanced Database Crawler, and have gone as far in the investigation to exclude almost every field possible until I used Luke to uncover the problem.

How can I exclude document fields such as '_name' from being searchable to exclude this situation from returning the results not intended?

Comment: Currently used a field level search parameter in ADC to workaround the issue. Still would be great to know if the exclusion is still possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lucene documents have a RemoveField method. In your custom DatabaseCrawler you could normally remove fields from the document:

```
public class MyCustomCrawler : Sitecore.Search.Crawlers.DatabaseCrawler
{
        protected override void AddAllFields(Lucene.Net.Documents.Document document, Sitecore.Data.Items.Item item, bool versionSpecific)
        {
            document.RemoveField("SomeFieldName");
            ...
        }
}
```

In this case the fields are added after "AddAllFields'.  It happens in "AddSpecialFields", so you can do something like this:

```
protected override void AddSpecialFields(Document document, Sitecore.Data.Items.Item item)
{
    // Do nothing, don't call base.AddSpecialFields
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't physically removing the field '_name' from the document cause some issues for Lucene? While this will stop the field from being searched, I would think it would also remove a key identifiable field from Lucene.

Comment: It did not cause any issue in my tests, or in other indexes I have used that had no need for that field.  This is something Sitecore's base DatabaseCrawler does, not something Lucene depends on.